# How to print when touching only gameobject?

Tags: unity-game-engine, touch

I want to print `held` when I touch only the `gameObject`

```
public GameObject Gameobject;   
void Update () {
        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
        {
            print("held");
        }
    }
```

So this code prints `held` when I even touch outside the `gameobject`.I added the script to the `gameobject`.The answer must work on android too.

Comment: @Programmer I tried `OnDrag` method from your duplicate answer. And this works Perfectly :)

Comment: [How to open keyboard on android in UNITY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46501514/how-to-open-keyboard-on-android-in-unity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is event called OnMouseOver()

```
void OnMouseOver()
{
    if (Input.GetAxis("Fire1"))
        {
            print("held");
        }
}
```

For Android is different, here you have a link:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/610440/on-touch-event-on-game-object-on-android-2d.html

They explain how to get the position of the touch and shoot a ray to know if it impacts your object.

Comment: Thanks I think got it.

Comment: `Input.GetButton` inside `OnMouseOver`?  Not good. 1.Use the EventSystem or raycast. This will prevent many problems such as clicks going through UI Object.

Comment: You're right, I corrected it.