# How to open keyboard on android in UNITY?

Tags: unity-game-engine, keyboard

I have a simple `button`. I want to when I click it this must open a keyboard.I tried `TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("")`..but this opens a new **page**(could not change design) with keyboard. I just need a keyboard.

Comment: This was answered in your last question. You **can't** change the skin of the keyword. What you can do is design and implement your own keyboard.

Comment: You want to say Unity not able to  open just a keyboard...in my android I have so much apps...and all of them opens the **same keyboard**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to add the second parameter which defines what keyboard to use. Try to follow the example from the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchScreenKeyboard.Open.html):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string stringToEdit = "Hello World";
    private TouchScreenKeyboard keyboard;

    // Opens native keyboard
    void OnGUI()
    {
        stringToEdit = GUI.TextField(new Rect(10, 10, 200, 30), stringToEdit, 30);

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 50, 200, 100), "Default"))
        {
            keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.Default);
        }
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 150, 200, 100), "ASCIICapable"))
        {
            keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.ASCIICapable);
        }
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 250, 200, 100), "Numbers and Punctuation"))
        {
            keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.NumbersAndPunctuation);
        }
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 350, 200, 100), "URL"))
        {
            keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.URL);
        }
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 450, 200, 100), "NumberPad"))
        {
            keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.NumberPad);
        }
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 550, 200, 100), "PhonePad"))
        {
            keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.PhonePad);
        }
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 650, 200, 100), "NamePhonePad"))
        {
            keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.NamePhonePad);
        }
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 750, 200, 100), "EmailAddress"))
        {
            keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.EmailAddress);
        }
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 850, 200, 100), "Social"))
        {
            keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.Social);
        }
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 950, 200, 100), "Search"))
        {
            keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.Search);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code..but every button opens with inputpage